# how to not color nan values when making a contour plot with matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh, colormap

I am trying to plot a tri/quad mesh along with results on that mesh. I am plotting results of a CFD simulation.

I am using `matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection` to plot because it handles non-tri elements, where other methods only support tri elements.

my current code works fine, but when I try to plot results where some cells have no water (have them set to `np.nan` right now), the plotting crashes and the contour colors get all screwed up.

My current code is:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet
polys = element_coords #list of Nx2 np.arrays containing the coordinates of each element polygon)
facecolors = element_values #np array of values at each element, same length as polys
pc = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection(polys, cmap=cmap)
pc.set_array(facecolors)
ax.add_collection(pc)
ax.plot()
```

When element_values does not contain any nan values, it works fine and looks something like this:

[image: works]

However, when `element_values` does contain nan values, it crashes and I get this error:

```
C:\Users\deden\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py:527: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  xa[xa < 0] = -1
```

I played around with `element_values` and can confirm this only happens when `nan` values are present.

I initially tried to ignore the `nan` values by doing this just to make them clear:

```
pc.cmap.set_bad(color='white',alpha=0)
```

But I still get the same error.

So... I tried setting all the `nan` values to `-999` then trying to cut off the colormap like this:

```
vmin = np.nanmin(facecolors)
vmax = np.nanmax(facecolors)
facecolors[np.isnan(facecolors)] = -999
pc.cmap.set_under(color='white',alpha=0)
```

then tried to set the limits of the colormap based on other stack questions I've seen..like:

```
pc.cmap.set_clim(vmin,vmax)
```

but then I get:

```
AttributeError: 'ListedColormap' object has no attribute 'set_clim'
```

I'm out of ideas here...can anyone help me? I just want to NOT COLOR any element where the value is nan.

To reproduce my error..you can try using this dummy data:

```
polys = [np.array([[ 223769.2075899 , 1445713.24572239],
                   [ 223769.48419606, 1445717.09102757],
                   [ 223764.48282055, 1445714.84782264]]),
         np.array([[ 223757.9584215 , 1445716.57576502],
                   [ 223764.48282055, 1445714.84782264],
                   [ 223762.05868674, 1445720.48031478]])]
facecolors = np.array([np.nan, 1]) #will work if you replace np.nan with a number
```

SIDE NOTE - if anyone knows how I can plot this mesh+data without polycollections that'd be great..it includes 3 and 4 sided mesh elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib's colormapping mechanics come from a time when `numpy.nan` wasn't around. Instead it works with masked arrays.

```
facecolors = np.ma.array(facecolors, mask=np.isnan(facecolors))
```

---

Concerning the other error you get, note that `.set_clim` is an attribute of the color**bar**, not the color**map**.

---

Finally, if your mesh contained only 3-sided elements, you could use `tripcolor`, but that won't work with 4-sided meshes.

Comment: god you're a legend..thanks - worked perfectly, saw something about using a masked array but couldnt figure out what I was doing

Comment: are you aware of another way I could plot n-sided mesh results where I would be able to plot a smooth colormap? polycollections only supports 1 color per face - if i'm not mistaken, can look chunky

Comment: Well, `tripcolor`  would support gouraud shading, but as stated in the answer it would require all 3-sided triangles. Of course you could let your mesh be recalculated with the in-build triangulation methods.

Comment: ya - screws up the outline of the mesh though, connecting nodes together that don't make sense...an option for me would be do split the quad elements in tris and supply the connectivity, if that's my only option I can do it but was hoping there'd be something else

Comment: Not really. Contour plots would also need triangles. One option, if your know the outline of your mesh, would be to let the triangulation do its job, but then mask out all everything outside the region of interest.

Comment: could I not just supply the triangulation connectivity?

Comment: Yes, if you have that available. (Sorry, for the confusion. The "not really" was about the "something else", it's totally possible to manually split the quad elements, arrive at triangles and supply them to tripcolor. It may be a little work to get the format right though.)